# Java Spring 4 - why i need manually scan for beans in WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, wicket, spring-4, wicket-1.6

I'm trying to setup a Web application with Spring 4.1 and Wicket 6.18. I want to use the full code approach. I have two test classes annotated with `@Configuration` and with `@Bean`. I want them to be discovered when i startup my app in Tomcat but it is not working unless i *manually* scan the base package in my custom `WebApplicationInitialzer`. By manually i mean to invoke [AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.scan()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.html#scan-java.lang.String...-).

I looked through quite a few tutorials about the code based approach and didn't saw they do this. Even in the [official spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) they don't do this.

What i'm doing wrong that i need this and how to correct it?

My custom `WebApplicationInitialzer` looks like this:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebAppInitializer.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        context.scan("pl.myhouse"); //why do i need this???

        FilterRegistration filter = container.addFilter("wicket.myproject", WicketFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("applicationClassName", WicketApplication.class.getName());
        filter.setInitParameter(WicketFilter.FILTER_MAPPING_PARAM, "/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: You skipped a line in the tutorial: `rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);`

Comment: have you used @ComponentScan to actually pick up the annotations and all automatically on startup?

Comment: Your both comments are correct: i didnt have @ComponentScan so i had to manually scan. I added the `context.register()` and @ComponentScan and removed the `context.scan()` and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You both `@The Head Rush` and `@Aeseir` are correct. I was missing the `rootContext.register(Appconfig.class)` as well as the `@ComponentScan`. I even could share my knowledge further: [Configuring Spring Wicket using Java Conf instead of xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947732/configuring-spring-wicket-using-java-conf-instead-of-xml) :)