# Configuring Spring Wicket using Java Conf instead of xml

Tags: java, spring, wicket, spring-java-config

I'use Spring for a short time, but to wicket I am newbie. But I would like to give a try to this framework.

I would like to configure this both frameworks togheter. But I would like to avoid usage of xml configuration file.

I know that wicket can be configured that way, according to this:

http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/single.html#helloWorld_2
and this:

https://github.com/bitstorm/Wicket-tutorial-examples/tree/master/SpringInjectionExample

But for now I am getting only errors:

```
lis 15, 2014 4:31:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter com.derp.wicket.ProjectFilter
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication.setMetaData(Lorg/apache/wicket/MetaDataKey;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/wicket/Application;
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.<init>(SpringComponentInjector.java:115)
    at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.<init>(SpringComponentInjector.java:92)
    at com.derp.wicket.WicketApplication.init(WicketApplication.java:52)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.initApplication(Application.java:823)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:424)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

lis 15, 2014 4:31:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
lis 15, 2014 4:31:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Here my confs:

```
package com.derp.common.init;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        // Allow to use Put and Delete method for REST architecture
        registerHiddenFieldFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerHiddenFieldFilter(ServletContext aContext) {
        aContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", new HiddenHttpMethodFilter()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null ,true, "/*"); 
    }
}


package com.derp.common.init;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.derp")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class WebAppConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES = "services.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON = "common.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS = "cms.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        //sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_SERVICES),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_COMMON),
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN_CMS)
                });
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        return properties;  
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

}

package com.derp.wicket;

import org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;

import com.derp.wicket.ejbBean.EnterpriseMessage;

public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SpringBean
    private EnterpriseMessage enterpriseMessage;

    public HomePage(final PageParameters parameters) {
        super(parameters);

        add(new Label("message", enterpriseMessage.message));
    }
}

package com.derp.wicket;


import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;

import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter;

@WebFilter(value = "/*", initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "applicationClassName", value = "com.derp.wicket.WicketApplication"), 
        @WebInitParam(name="filterMappingUrlPattern", value="/*")
})
public class ProjectFilter extends WicketFilter {
}



package com.derp.wicket;

import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;


/**
 * Application object for your web application. If you want to run this application without deploying, run the Start class.
 * 
 * @see org.wicketTutorial.Start#main(String[])
 */
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {
    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#getHomePage()
     */
    @Override
    public Class<HomePage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.Application#init()
     */
    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        ctx.scan("com.derp.wicket.ejbBean");
        ctx.refresh();

        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this, ctx));
    }
}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2> <wicket:container wicket:id="message"></wicket:container></h2>     
        wwiicckkeet
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone could help me struggle with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your are mixing Wicket with Spring Web MVC. Below i pasted some of my code or you can try something found on github: Spring Boot + Wicket: https://github.com/Pentadrago/spring-boot-example-wicket

My `WebApplicationInitializer` looks like this:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        context.register(ApplicationConfiguration.class);

        FilterRegistration filter = container.addFilter("wicket.myproject", WicketFilter.class);
        filter.setInitParameter("applicationClassName", WicketApplication.class.getName());
        filter.setInitParameter(WicketFilter.FILTER_MAPPING_PARAM, "/*");
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
```

The `ApplicationConfiguration` class used there looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public TestService testService(){
        return new TestServiceImpl();
    }

}
```

My inherited `WebApplication` class looks like this:

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return HomePage.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        super.init();
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new SpringComponentInjector(this));
    }
}
```

In your POM you should have this deps:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
    <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```